# Play Audio(mp3) in every page on Windows Store Apps C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, mp3

I have multiple pages on Windows Store App project. In MainPage backround audio start playing but when i click button and go other page, music has stopped. there is one background audio which must play every page and every page has their own audio(mp3).(as i know MediaElement can play only one audio at a time)

i tried this
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7e39ca/play-audion-on-background-in-windows-store-apps/

it works background but when change page audio has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use mediaelement, use background audio player and if you are using Background audio player already then it should work like you want. If not then although it should work anyways because its running in the background but you can try this

On every page Pause Background player on onNavigatedFrom event and Play it back onNavigatedTo event

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Playing) && (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.CanSeek))
        {
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Pause();
        }
    }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Pause) 
            {
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
            }
    }
```

Comment: BackgroundAudioPlayer give me error. tried to add
using Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio; but it gives me error too.

Comment: What is the error? You have to create a background audio app first you know that right?

Comment: yes but i guess BackgroundAudioPlayer need Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio library, when i tried to add project it gives error. i think windows store app project dont have that library.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the above background player code in your App.xaml/App.xaml.cs?

Comment: when i add these codes to app.xaml it gives error
<MediaElement AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" x:Name="back_audio" Source="Assets/MainPage_Pic/music/audio.mp3" AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" IsLooping="True"/>

Comment: Does it also give an error when you add it in the resources block?

Comment: thanks for the reply, no it doesnt give error when i add codes in <Application.Resources> block but it doesnt start playing audio.

Comment: If you want, upload your project to skydrive and leave a link here, I will have a look at it

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=CA78F8D7CB976033!1083&authkey=!AK7LNJHB8i1dfU8&ithint=file%2c.rar thanks

Comment: Rajeev Bhatia have any solution?